# Single SQL query to pull recent two nodes from each node type

Tags: 7, nodes, database

As mentioned in the title, I was wondering how this can be achieved with single SQL query. All I need is the node ID from node table that matches the given criteria.

Comment: This is really more of an SQL question than a Drupal question.

Comment: @tim to answer this you would need to know drupal's database scheme. It could be reworded to be a pure SQL question, but I don't see any reason migrating this to SO, though it is borderline.

Comment: @googletorp I agreed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$node_types = node_get_types(); // or create own object of node types
$query = $types = array();

foreach($node_types AS $type){
  $query[] = "(SELECT node.* FROM {node} node WHERE node.status <> 0 AND node.type = '%s' ORDER BY node.nid DESC LIMIT 2)";
  $types[] = $type->type;
}

$query = implode(' UNION ', $query);
$result = db_query($query, $types);

$items = '';
while($row = db_fetch_object($result)){
  $items[] = l($row->title, 'node/'. $row->nid);
}

print theme_item_list($items);
```

Execute time: 0.002s

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with views, using attachments. However it will not be a single SQL query.

It will however be easier to maintain (as it uses the views GUI) going forward (especially if you have multiple developers in your team).